# Relative import of a module with a dependency

Tags: python, python-import

I have a python script that imports another class called `myClass` from a relative path. Next to `myClass.py` lies a csv-file from which a dataframe is generated when calling `myClass()`. This dependency on the file forces me to change the directory to the relative path when creating an instance of myClass:

```
currentPath = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append("../../../ClassFolder/")  # relative folder
os.chdir(libPath)
from myScript import myClass
myObj = myClass() 
os.chdir(currentPath)
```

Is there a way to do this without having to manually jump directories?

Comment: The module has a bug. It should be using something like the [`importlib.resources`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.resources.html) module to access a CSV file included in the same package, not a raw relative path.

Comment: (For example, something like `importlib.resources.files('ClassFolder').joinpath('data.csv')` instead of `./data.csv'`.)